# WSO2 Aggregator in Java DSL

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any sample available with WSO2 aggregator using Java DSL ?

I couldn't find any example or blogs based on Java DSL. It could really helpful for me.

Regards
Guru

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB is based on a declarative configuration approach and uses an XML-based DSL instead of a Java-like DSL, so your requirement can be implemented using those xml/xpath configurations. 

If it doesn't give enough control to accomplish your task, custom mediators that use plain Java[1] will be a good option. Scripting-language based mediators[2] and maybe POJO command mediators[3] can also be useful in this case.

---

1. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Writing+a+WSO2+ESB+Mediator
2. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Script+Mediator
3. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/POJOCommand+Mediator

Answer (score 0):

I think you look for domain specific language (like dsl in drools), right?
wso2 brs only supports (drl), from their document. 
I am also looking for the answer.

Comment: To give you more ideas dsl are used extensively in Camel integration framework. In most other integration framework/esb the concept of integration is not mostly emphasized or used . It is just simple as you can accomplish the undo-able using the java and the integration framework/esb has necessary APIs to do them.